# connect two raspberry pi via ethernet cable

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I am using python to connect two raspberry pi via serial port. one pi will send data to another pi. and another pi will do some specfic task depending on received data. can i use ethernet port for this function? Is there any function similar to serial.read() and serial.available() in case of ethernet port.

I wrote the simple server program

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostname()
port=12345
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'got connection from',addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')

    c.close()
```

and client program is

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)        
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345               
s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

error is no connection is made because target machine actively refuse it. what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ethernet for this purpose. You can create a [TCP](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) connection between the two machines. Much like a serial connection, this will give you a bidrectional, byte stream.

Comment: sir please give one example. suppose one pi has static ip address 192.168.0.12 and other one is 192.168.0.21

Comment: @AkashNil I'm not sure what you want an example of. You can punch "python TCP example" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: import socket
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host=socket.gethostname()
    port=12345
    s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print 'got connection from',addr
        c.send('Thank you for connecting')

        c.close()